# cannot add a reference to wmp.dll inc# visual 2010

Tags: c#, dll, wmp, wmplib

I use WMPlib in my program in C# (Visual 2010). I cannot make a reference to wpm.dll. There is no windows media player or smth like this in COM, when I browse to wmp.dll, there is an error "cannot add a reference to ...wmp.dll. please ....." After hours or googling I still don't find a good answer.
P.S. My wmp.dll is not in system32 folder but in C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-mediaplayer-core_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.20683_none_089d6f4d399eff17

Comment: have you thought about adding a reference to that DLL from it's location and setting the `copy local property to `True` or copy it manually also can you show the code of how you are creating an `Instance` to that particular .DLL ??

Comment: All Windows DLLs are in the WinSxS folder, the ones you see in System32 are just hardlinks to the real file in winsxs.  Getting your Windows install fixed is not on topic here.